# Do not want <footer> HTML tag when using footer region

Tags: theming

After running W3 Markup Validator on a site of mine, I received the following error:

> Line 219, Column 57: element "footer" undefined
>
> `<footer id="footer" class="region region-footer">`

Whether or not this is actually an issue, bad style, or what, I've decided that I *don't* want Drupal using the HTML footer tag. Is there a way that I can change this and have it just create yet another div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using zen theme there is a 'region--footer.tpl.php' in the templates you can change it from there. ( i don't know about other themes maybe they have it too)

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I didn't think of this. I actually _am_ using Zen as my base theme. Got into work today and a coworker actually had already figured it out, and this is what she did.

Answer (score 2):

did the validator know you where using an HTML5 site?
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_footer.asp

... anyways you can always edit `page.tpl.php` or `html.tpl.php` for your theme to change global page markup like this to however you want.

Comment: Well, it should detect automatically, but even if I set it to HTML5 it gave the error. Figured it out though - I'm using Zen as my base theme and editing the 'region--footer.tpl.php' did the trick.